# Wireguard - Can't connect to private url

Tags: windows, debian, vpn, wireguard

We moved from OpenVPN to Wireguard recently. Our sales people need access to a private URL on our infra accessed via VPN. The domain is resolved by a private DNS.

Everyone in the company managed to set up Wireguard without problem except one sales person and we can't really figure out why. When connected to Wireguard and trying to access the URL, the connection hangs and fail. The client is on Windows 10.

Here's a list of the different tests we managed to do :

- Activate the Wireguard connection and go to the private URL on different browsers : DOES NOT WORK. The connection hangs until timeout.
- Activate the old OpenVPN connection and do the same test (Wireguard deactivated) : WORKS. This was the old way the sales person used to connect and never had a problem with it.
- Deactivate client Firewall and do test 1 : DOES NOT WORK. We thought a firewall rule might be blocking outbound traffic.
- Test client config file on a different machine : WORKS. It means the config file and server file are OK. The firewall on server side is OK too.
- Reinstall Wireguard and do test 1 : DOES NOT WORK.
- Ping URL : WORKS and the right ip is resolved.
- Curl URL : DOES NOT WORK. It hangs and does not give any return text.
- Update Network drivers and Update Windows, then do test 1 : DOES NOT WORK.
- Check Nginx access logs after test 1 : No access from client.

The problem seems to come from the sales person's PC since their conf file works as expected on a different machine. There are no errors on the Wireguard logs client side and the peer is listed as activated on server side.

Any idea on what to check next ?

Comment: personally, I'd do a `traceroute`

Comment: Traceroute works and give the right route